# Show that the poles of analytic function $f$ cannot have a limit point in $G$.

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, complex-integration

> If $f: G \longrightarrow \mathbb C$ is analytic except for poles, then show that the poles of $f$ cannot have any limit point in $G$.

**My attempt** $:$

If the poles of $f$ has a limit point in $G$ then zeroes of $\dfrac {1} {f}$ has a limit point in $G$. Hence by identity theorem we have $\dfrac {1} {f} \equiv 0$ on $G$. But then there is no point in $G$ where $f$ can be analytic, a contradiction.

Is it the correct reasoning? If all the points of $G$ are poles of $f$ then vacuously the analyticity of $f$ follows. But then the above reasoning needs some modification. Isn't it? Please give me some suggestion regarding this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: $\frac{1}{f}$ doesn't have to be analytic/holomorphic (think to $f$ having many zeros). What you need is the definition of meromorphic (ie. analytic except some poles) which excludes limit points of zeros or poles. In other words let $a$ be the limit point of the poles. $f$ is meromorphic at $z=a$ iff for some $k$, $f(z) (z-a)^k)$ is analytic at $z=a$, contradicting that $a$ was the limit of a sequence of poles.

Answer (score 1):

I think in Conway's book, poles should be **isolated singularities**. Hence the limit point of poles should not be a pole.

Let $a$ be the limit point of poles, then there is $a_n\rightarrow a$ where $a_n$ are poles. Since $f$ is analytic at $a$, we can find $r$ such that $f$ is analytic on $B_r(a)\subset G$. Pick $a_k\in B_r(a)-\{a\}$, and a sequence $\{z_n\}\subset B_r(a)$ such that $z_n\rightarrow a_k$. Then $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} f(z_n) = f(a_k)\neq \infty$ contradicting that $a_k$ is a pole.